# Confusions with USB booting with Gigabyte 945GCM-S2L Main board

Tags: windows

Hey guys i am using Gigabyte 945GCM-S2L Mainboard

and i created a usb bootable device using Rufus and when i tried to boot form the existing options in the BIOS which are-

Hard disk
CDROM
ZIP
USB-FDD
USB-ZIP
USB-CDROOM
USB-HDD

i have tried all the usb  options that are available but still fails and windows 8  still boots...a little help...

thanks in advance..

Comment: Some USB Drive may identify itself as HDD. Check your BIOS setting and check the HDD Boot Priority (when USB is plugged in) you might find your USB disk listed there as HDD.

Answer (score 0):

1. Press F12 to enter boot menu
2. Ignore all USB-whatever options
3. Select + Hard Disk option instead
4. Another menu apperars, with USB-HDD0 and other HDD drives
5. Choose USB-HDD0

This worked with my 945GCM-S2L Motherboard with Bios release F7.
Like in arvhin's answer.

Answer (score -1):

choose HARD DISK in Boot Menu and then you can see your bootable usb there

Comment: Choosing `Hard Disk` will boot you into Windows (which is where it is installed). 

"*and then you can see your bootable usb there*" Huh? Please clarify.

Comment: As @RsyaStudios said, this usually isn't the case. Most BIOS's are intelligent enough to differentiate between USB and internal HDDs. This is incorrect in 90% of cases.